# Box-sizing con estado hover

Tags: css, css3

Me gustaría utilizar la propiedad box-sizing para poder hacer un div modificando su apariencia en el estado hover, incluyéndole un borde y un padding. Pero tengo un problema, cuando incluyo el border y el padding en el estado hover con la propiedad box-sizing activada, el texto del div se desplaza hacia abajo porque debe incluir el borde y el padding (si no utilizo box-sizing ocurre igual)

Hay podría explicarme un poco más detenidamente cómo puedo utilizar la propiedad box-sizing para simular un efecto de cambio de estado??

Gracias.

Comment: Sería mejor agregar tu código CSS con respecto a tu problema y que es lo que quieres lograr exactamente. Recuerda que los textos se deben encerrar entre la etiqueta ```<p> </p>``` y tiene algunos estilos predefinido

Comment: Es necesario que pongas tu ejemplo con el codigo de lo que has intentado hasta el momento, te dejo un articulo del centro de ayuda de [como crear un ejemplo minimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)